# List all members of a class in Pike

Tags: pike

In Pike, it is possible to retrieve all members of an object by calling `indices()`. Is it also possible to see all members of a class without instantiating it?

```
> class A {int foo; string bar;};
> A a = A();
> indices(a);
(1) Result: ({ /* 2 elements */
                "foo",
                "bar"
            })
> indices(A);
(2) Result: ({ })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, although output won't be as friendly as `indices` one. You need to use `_describe_program` function, like this:

```
> _describe_program(A);
(4) Result: ({ /* 2 elements */
            ({ /* 7 elements */
                0,
                "foo",
                int,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0
            }),
            ({ /* 7 elements */
                0,
                "bar",
                string,
                0,
                16,
                0,
                0
            })
        })
```

Comment: Thank you! It is also worth pointing out that calling `indices()` on a class/program returns its constant members (this is not documented though):
`> class A { constant nono = 0; }
> indices(A);
(9) Result: ({ /* 1 element */
                "nono"
            })
`